# I can't update a record in my database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a system where i want to up date a record, change its status between 0 and 1. To turn a feature on or off. This is my form to turn it on or off:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
            <label>
                Select Market: 
                    <select name="market" id="market">
                        <option value="EUR/USD">EUR/USD</option>
                        <option value="gbpusd">GBP/USD</option>
                        <option value="chfusd">CHF/USD</option>
                        <option value="brent">Brent</option>
                        <option value="GOLD">Gold</option>
                        <option value="downjones">Down Jones</option>      
                    </select>
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="submit" name="on" id="on" value="On">
                <input type="submit" name="off" id="off" value="Off">
            </label>
        </form>
```

Now this is the php for updating the record:

```
if(isset($_POST['on']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['market']))
    {
        if($_POST['market'] == 'EUR/USD')
            $market_id = '1';

        $updateRecord = mysql_query("UPDATE current_trades SET status='1' WHERE id='$market_id'");

        //Update record by turning it on
        echo "market on";
    }
}
```

So as you can see, the user would select a value from the drop down menu and the hit on or off to turn that feature on or off. But when i click on (Which is the only one with logic so far) it doesn't update my record, any see anything wrong with that?

I don't think its anything to do with permissions because i have other pages editing other tables in my database.

also if i go into phpMyAdmin and run the Mysql from there it works.

I have also tested just grabbing some records from my database and this works just fine.

So any ideas?

Comment: No error at all. Just doesn't update... It's totally got me!

Comment: +1 @DanielA.White - firstly, makes sure that the conditions of the outer `if`s are met by putting `echo` statements inside them and making sure you can see the results, once you know the code reaches the `mysql_query()` call (maybe `echo` the query just before it), temporarily change it to `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error())` and see what MySQL says went wrong.

Comment: Try `$result = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error())` to ensure that the query is actually running. You might have to forgotten to do something earlier on in the code, like connecting to the db, or are connecting with incorrect credentials. NEVER assume a query succeeded. ALWAYS check for error conditions.

Comment: thats a good idea, i put the 'or die' part in, still nothing. I have put echo's in where so i know what its done, i also put if($updateRecord) statement and it was always true :S

Comment: you only need it to be updated when the user posts market=EUR/USD ?

Comment: Well for i want it. But i at some point there would be more markets being added to it. @hydrarulz

Comment: Just a reminder to ensure that you fill in the HTML form's `action` attribute.

Comment: I left it blank so it posts to itself, is that a bad practice?

Comment: @ragebunny, so the HTML form above is output by the PHP script?

Comment: @MarcusAdams Yeah they're in the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `$market_id` is not defined (except when `$_POST['market'] == 'EUR/USD'`), so the updated query will fail (it will look for records `WHERE id=''`, which is probably none).

Maybe you also want the `mysql_query` and `echo` lines inside the `if`? In this case, you need `{` and `}` around the whole block:

```
if($_POST['market'] == 'EUR/USD') {
    $market_id = '1';
    $updateRecord = mysql_query("UPDATE current_trades SET status='1' WHERE id='$market_id'");
    //Update record by turning it on
    echo "market on";
}
```

**EDIT**

I re-read your question, and now I think the code I suggested is not what you need. What you need is to have a proper `$market_id` set for each possible selected value from `#market`. The easiest solution would be to make the `value` attribute of each `<option>` the market id, like

```
<option value="1">EUR/USD</option>
```

Then you PHP you'd just do `$market_id = is_numeric($_POST['market']) ? $_POST['market'] : 0;`.

If you don't want that, you'll need a `switch` statement on your PHP, or a bunch of `if/else`. The important thing here is that you need a different `$market_id` set for each situation, so you can run the right query based on that.

Comment: But surely because i know that it goes into the if($_POST['market'] == 'EUR/USD') statement then i know that $market_id is always set?

Comment: It will be set if the `if` condition is true, otherwise it won't be set, and the query won't run. If you need to run the query with a different `$market_id`, ignore my suggestion, and make sure to set `$market_id` (in an `else`, for example).

Comment: Just tried that and it didn't work.... There must be something silly i'm doing. But i can't figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: Please see my edit. On a side note: isn't it "Dow Jones" (not "Down")?

Comment: AAAAAAAAaaahahahaha good spot there... Lucky this isn't going live any time soon! :P

Comment: This still didn't work.... It seems to run the query just fine, plus ii print the $market_id variable to the screen to check there is a value in it and there is.

Comment: I'm out of ideas! If you checked that (a) your code is entering all `if` statements, (b) it's reaching the `mysql_query` line, (c) the query syntax is okay, (d) `$market_id` is set, and (e) PHP issues no errors, then I don't know! So you say you run this, then go to phpMyAdmin and the record was not updated?

Comment: Yeah i know. I'm starting to think that there is a problem with the database. It can't be a problem with the log in details because it manages to select the records if i ask for them. Yeah i refresh the page in phpMyAdmin, nothing, even tried logging out and back in again.

Comment: Thanks for you help anyway, i think its not the PHP that is the problem, it must be something to do with the database, maybe im using a reserved word somewhere a long the line.

Comment: I'm not sure. Your query seems okay (only you don't need the single quotes around the values if the columns are numeric, but it should work anyway)